# how to load form in <div> on button click using HTML/ JS

Tags: javascript

```html
<html>
<body>
<section>
  <div>
    <section class="upper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" id="button1" class="button1">Button1</a>
              <li><a href="#" id="button2" class="button2">Button2</a>
              <li><a href="#" id="button3" class="button3">Button3</a>
            </ul>            
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    </div>
    <div>
    <section class="lower"> 
    <div class="loadForm" id = "loadForm">
    </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>

<form action="#" id="form_1" method="post" name="form_1" style="display:none">
  <div class="nameDiv"  style="alignment-adjust:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-top:auto">
   <div id="infoPopup">
   <span>Select Name</span>
     <input id="nameFile" name="nameFile" type="file">
     <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"/> 
     <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />  
  </div>&nbsp;
 </div>
 </form>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  /*
    $("#button1").click(function() {
            $("#form_1").show();
        }); */
  });
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

i have created 2 section one above other and want to load different forms in lower section (  division in section) depending on buttons (click) from above section using JS
Right now, i'm adding snippet for 1 for only but i need to load form_1, form_2 and so on as per the button click button1, button2 and so on.

Comment: Share your code...because your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<section>
  <div>
    <section class="upper">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Menu
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" id="button1" class="button1" onclick="displayform1()">Button1</a>
              <li><a href="#" id="button2" class="button2" onclick="displayform2()">Button2</a>
              <li><a href="#" id="button3" class="button3" onclick="displayform3()">Button3</a>
            </ul>            
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    </div>
    <div>
    <section class="lower"> 
    <div class="loadForm" id = "loadForm">
    </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</section>

<form action="#" id="form_1" method="post" name="form_1" style="display:none">
  <div class="nameDiv"  style="alignment-adjust:auto; margin-left:auto; margin-top:auto">
   <div id="infoPopup">
   <span>Select Name</span>
     <input id="nameFile" name="nameFile" type="file">
     <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Ok"/> 
     <input type="button" id="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />  
  </div>&nbsp;
 </div>
 </form>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function displayform1(){
     document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("form_2").style.display = "none";
 }
 function displayform2(){
     document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("form_2").style.display = "block";
 }
 //excluded the 3rd one
 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without codes, can't help much but the general flow is that you can assign the onclick events for the different buttons and setting the style of the form to:

```
display:none;
```

the onclick function should go something like

```
//remember to set the form id for this to work
function foo(){
    document.getElementById("form id here").style.display = "block";
    //if you need to show only one then use set the other one to none
    document.getElementById("the other form id here").style.display = "none";
}
```

you need 2 different function for 2 buttons using this method.

Comment: i tried it the same way, but the problem is, though forms are in hidden condition, they have got their own place and making them visible one-by one will not show them at the very upper layer of stack.

Comment: @Kittu, Try it with display:none. It is known that display:hidden will take the space but display:none will not take up any of the space. A quick search gives the explanation: display:none will not be available in the page and does not occupy any space. visibility:hidden hides an element, but it will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout. visibility:hidden preserve the space, whereas display:none doesn't preserve the space.

Comment: i tried with style="display:none" only.. and still it's reserving the space.